# PowerShell - Directory - Side by side Comparison

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I need to compare two directory structures side by side in Power shell however i'm not able to do that. 
Looking for a output like this

```
Filename   Dir1     Dir2      File exists in Dir1 File exists in Dir2
ABC.txt    c:\data  d:\data   True                False  
ABD.txt    c:\data  d:\data   False               False
ADC.txt    c:\data  d:\data   True                True

$SourceFiles = Get-ChildItem 'c:\data' -File 
$destFiles = Get-ChildItem 'd:\Data' -File 
Compare-Object $sourceFiles $destFiles -IncludeEqual -ExcludeDifferent -Property Name| ForEach-Object { 
   [PSCustomObject]@{ 
   Name = $_.Name 
   Path1 = ($SourceFiles | Where-Object Name -eq $_.Name).Directory 
   Path2 = ($destFiles | Where-Object Name -eq $_.Name).Directory } 
}
```

Comment: What have you tried, and how has what you've tried failed? Ideally, you should provide a [MCVE] of what you've tried, and include specific information on how it failed, with error messages and/or erroneous output. [SO] is not a code-writing service; the best questions are those which provide useful information so that those who answer can guide you to devising your own correct answer. See [Ask] a Good Question.

Comment: Utilize `Compare-Object (dir c:\data) (dir d:\data) -IncludeEqual`?

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
$DirSourceName='c:\temp'
$DirDestName='c:\temp2'

$SourceFiles = Get-ChildItem $DirSourceName -File 
$destFiles   = Get-ChildItem $DirDestName -File 

Compare-Object $sourceFiles $destFiles   -Property Name -IncludeEqual | %{
    [pscustomobject]@{
        FileName=$_.Name
        Dir1=$DirSourceName
        Dir2=$DirDestName
        "File exists in Dir1"=($_.SideIndicator -eq "==" -or $_.SideIndicator -eq "<=")
        "File exists in Dir2"=($_.SideIndicator -eq "==" -or $_.SideIndicator -eq "=>")
    }

}
```

Comment: i tried that already and was getting below error. Compare-Object : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'ReferenceObject' because it is null.
At line:7 char:16
+ Compare-Object $sourceFiles $destFiles   -Property Name -IncludeEqual ...
+                ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Compare-Object], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CompareObjectCommand

Comment: check your PowerShell version and eventualy update. check if dir1 and dir2 exist on server where you ru your script and if you have access for them

Comment: with my script you must change Dirsourcename and dirdestname

Comment: lol not that dum. I wrote similar script myself, had almost similar error.Something wrong with script.